# Looks to be an obscure page rendering problem

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown-rendering

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694404/using-watin-through-mbunit-to-test-asp-net-mvc-web-application) looks to be written correctly, however the link that should read "this page" is extended to include all text in the question up to the next link. I can't see any error in the question, am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed by just editing the question.

Sometimes old questions have bad formatting due to bugs in the markdown handling *at the time the post was last saved*. A lot of bugs have been fixed over time, but some require posts to be re-rendered before the displayed state is correct.

Editing forces a fresh rendering and fixes those issues - unless the bug hasn't been fixed yet, obviously, but that was not the case for this question.

Comment: You spoiled my fun! I was all gearing up to post a snide "no repro" comment.

Comment: Seems so obvious now :) thanks for that