# Something funny happened here

Tags: bug, markdown

https://stackoverflow.com/a/803323

Looks like the font of the code block overflowed! (FFx, Chrome. And in IE8 it's even weider)

> [image]

Comment: Congrats for finding such thing :) Absolutley this is bug. 1 hour ago even I posted a bug  :)

Comment: Actually this is even worse than it looks- the last few paragraphs of that answer are cut off (try clicking "edit" to see). However, I wasn't able to reproduce the problem in the [formatting sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/178583/176330).

Comment: That happens on old posts. Some rendering bugs have been fixed since, but the stored html doesn't get regenerated until a post is edited. I did just that. (Not the first time I see that specific bug.)

Comment: @DavidRobinson: Matt. re-rendered it, now its good.But what was the problem? The length of answer?

Comment: @Anoop Vaidya: there is not problem with that post. It was the victim of a bug that has already been fixed long ago.

Comment: Works for me (before the rerender). Then again, my screen is rotated (I'm currently trying to study while lying down :P) so my screen size is nonstandard.

Comment: "Something funny happened on my way to an SO answer".... ;)

Comment: Sorta dup: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125724/looks-to-be-an-obscure-page-rendering-problem

Comment: @Mat: Please post that as an answer.

Comment: @Lightness: bah, marked as dup instead. It's the same problem, same solution.