# Double scrollbar bug in a code sample within lists

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, meta

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/185856/2235132) for the following question, two sets of scrollbars appear in the code sample.  The code sample appears within a list.

[Equivalent of Class Loaders in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185836/equivalent-of-class-loaders-in-net)

The bug can be reproduced both in Chrome, IE and Firefox.

Comment: Another weird thing is that there is no repro in editing preview!

Comment: Same problem as [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125724/looks-to-be-an-obscure-page-rendering-problem/125728#125728) and others: old rendering of question was broken. Dummy edit re-renders.

Comment: @Mat - Oh that's why it was not reproduced in editing preview.